# OAuth2 authorization implementation in ServiceStack

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, servicestack

I am researching on OAuth2 authorization service implementation for our website.

We have WebServices implementation in ServiceStack with customAuthentication along with FB, LinkedIn AuthProviders enable. We are now planing to create our own custom OAuth2 authorization service, can any one of you suggest the best way to implement this. If there is an easy way to implement OAuth2 authorization in ServiceStack, it will be ideal to have both our OAuth Authentication Server, Resource Server in the same WebServer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to allow Sign Ins from a remote OAuth2 Server you can use [ServiceStack's OAuth2 Providers](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#oauth2-providers) where if there's currently no OAuth2 AuthProvider for the remote service you need to connect to you can implement your own by inheriting [OAuth2Provider.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Authentication.OAuth2/OAuth2Provider.cs), see the [existing OAuth2 AuthProvider implementations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Authentication.OAuth2) for examples.

But if you want to implement your OAuth2 Server, that's not built into 
ServiceStack. One solution is to use the ServiceStack IdentityServer plugin from 
[MacLeanElectrical/servicestack-authentication-identityserver](https://github.com/MacLeanElectrical/servicestack-authentication-identityserver).